# Why only part of a command is executed

Tags: user-commands

I have created a new command

```
command! Tags execute '!GTAGSFORCECPP=1 gtags' | cscope kill -1 | cscope add GTAGS
```

However, for some reason `cscope add GTAGS` doesn't execute when I execute `:Tags`.

Can someone explain what is the problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Vim has an odd way of parsing commands with optional arguments.  Wrapping the two `cscope` commands in `exec`s might produce better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `:command` does not (by default) accept the use of bars, as explaind in `:h :bar`. You may circumvent this by using the `-bar` option, see `:h :command-bar`:

```
command! -bar Tags execute '!GTAGSFORCECPP=1 gtags'
    \ | cscope kill -1
    \ | cscope add GTAGS
```

You can also wrap the functionality in a function, like this:

```
command! Tags :call s:tags()

function! s:tags()
  execute '!GTAGSFORCECPP=1 gtags' 
  cscope kill -1
  cscope add GTAGS
endfunction
```

Thanks to Christian Brabandt for mentioning the `-bar` in the comments.

Comment: Shouldn't `command -bar` just work?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Your suggestion (the one with a -bar option) almost worked. For some reason it doesn't execute `cscope add GTAGS`. Am I missing something?